# Select files in a directory from vector

Tags: r

How would I use `list.files()` to select only those files that are selected in a vector `files`?  The files in the directory are `.rds` files.

```
files <- c(20388, 20389, 20390)
```

I've tried this, but not returning anything.

```
list.files("Data/", pattern = paste0(files, ".rds"), full.names = TRUE)
```

Comment: why do you need to select them if you know the name and the directory? or is the actual name of the "real" files longer?

Comment: @NicE The directory has many more files than just those three.  So I need to just get the `file.list` of those three files within the directory.  And yes, the file directory names are much longer.

Comment: what is `file.list()` ? Shouldn't it be `list.files()` ?

Comment: @mtoto Yes, sorry; I've corrected it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument you're passing to `pattern =` is where things are going wrong I believe. This three-step approach might get you the desired result:

```
# Extract all .rds files
list <- list.files("Data/", pattern =".rds", full.names = TRUE)

# Define pattern for grepl
files <- c(20388, 20389, 20390)
pattern <- paste(files, sep="", collapse="|")

# Results in
pattern
[1] "20388|20389|20390" # grepl will interpret "|" as "or"

# Now we can subset list with the following
list[grepl(pattern,list)]
```

Comment: It can be done in one line: `list.files("Data/", pattern ="20388.rds|20389.rds|20390.rds", full.names = TRUE)` and maybe `list.files("Data/", pattern ="20388|20389|20390", full.names = TRUE)` if there are no other files with those numbers in their names.

Comment: @R.Schifini see update, this way it is more scalable if we have a long numerical vector `files`